# Swift: recursive structs with arrays?

Tags: swift

In Swift 2, why is this:

```
struct EditorIndex {
    var topLevelIndex: Int?
    var subIndex: EditorIndex?
}
```

...invalid code on account of having a recursive reference, while this:

```
struct EditorIndex {
    var topLevelIndex: Int?
    var subIndex: [EditorIndex]
}
```

...is apparently valid? I was under the impression that arrays were value types in Swift. If one is allowed, why isn't the other?

Or I guess more specifically, how can a Swift array be a struct given its fundamentally dynamic nature?

Comment: Unlike arrays, optionals store their values inline, therefore `EditorIndex?.none` would occupy the same amount of memory as `EditorIndex?.some(...)`, and therefore would require an infinite amount of memory to store recursively in your example. Take a look at [Mike Ash's blog post on Swift memory layout](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-01-exploring-swift-memory-layout-part-ii.html).